# FilterMultiValue on additional lookup column Skill:ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

I try to filter my sharepoint list based on some filters. Because the checkbox option "Allow Multiple Selections" does not work I am trying to build some own implementation using the `QueryFilter` functionality.

```
*URL?FilterName=Title&FilterMultiValue=Title1;Title2;Title3*
```

This is quite easy, but no I want to filter on a the additional lookup column which in my case is called `Skill:ID` but this will not work.

```
*URL?FilterName=Skill:ID&FilterMultiValue=5;12;23*
```

Who can help me on this issue?

Best regards,

Francois

Comment: Okay ofcourse I continued to search for a solution which I found by obseving the html sourcecode of the list. 

**Solution for my example:**

Skill_x003a_ID = Skill:ID
*URL?FilterName=Skill_x003a_ID&FilterMultiValue=5;12;23*

Comment: Can you please post the complete answer... with all the steps you did to configure the filter for List View ?